# ng-model rewrites the field value from database

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I have a email list in my DB with some default values, and I'm writing an edit section for those data. So let's say it has a section like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SenderEmail" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I want to mark this filed as the required if someone wants to submit any change, so I need to point to this element with a `ng-model`, but the problem if I add `ng-model` to this field:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SenderEmail" CssClass="form-control" ng-model="user.email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

It rewrites the previous value of this filed which is gotten from database -if there is any-.
Is there any way I can check this input without rewriting the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution:

```
angular.module('requiredForm', [])
    .controller('formController', [
        '$scope', function($scope) {
            // check if they have value from db
            $scope.email = '<%= SenderEmail.Text %>';
            $scope.sender = '<%= Sender.Text %>';
    }
    ]);
```